# CoreWindow.VisibilityChanged not firing

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Lets say that I have a Windows Store Class Library called ClassLibrary containing TestClass:

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {               
            coreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                CoreWindow coreWindow = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow;
                coreWindow.VisibilityChanged +=
                    (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(args.Visible ? "Foreground" : "Background");
                    };
            });
        }
    }
```

When the library is used by a Windows Store app, TestClass should be able to be initialized from a UI and non-UI thread:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
     {
         var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

         TestClass libraryClass;

         // Non-UI thread
         Task.Run(() => { libraryClass = new TestClass(); });
         // OR UI thread
         libraryClass = new TestClass();
     }
```

Unfortunately, when TestClass is initialized from a Non-UI thread the coreWindow.VisibilityChanged event doesn't fire.  While it *does* when TestClass is initialized from the main UI thread.

What am I doing incorrectly with the TestClass implementation?

Comment: Am I missing something? The VisibilityChanged event only fires when the UI changes.  Where are you changing the UI?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @paqogomex. The VisibilityChanged event will fire when the application is loaded and the Start Page (in this case MainPage.xaml) is loaded.

Comment: When you step through execution on a non-UI thread, does coreWindow exist yet?

Comment: @Tristan, I just edited the code, I meant to put the coreWindow declaration inside the Dispatcher.RunAsync lambda. With the current code example above, coreWindow is not null when TestClass() is initialized from a non-UI/worker thread. I am able to access properties like CoreWindow.Bounds.

Comment: I took a closer look at the code and realized that the Start page is visible/loaded and the VisibilityChanged event fires before the CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync lambda can execute on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

What I am trying to do is impossible, the application is behaving as expected when TestClass is initialized from a non-UI thread. The start page is visible/loaded and the VisibilityChanged event fires before the CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync lambda can execute on the UI thread. My VisibilityChanged handler will be able to catch all visibility changes except for the very first one.